# Vertically align fa-icon in a dynamically generated button

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am dynamically generating a button using jquery and adding an fa-icon in it, I need to vertically align that icon as the button contains two lines of string. The code:

```
$('#divContent').after('<center><button type="button" id="btnFiltersSave1" class="btn bg-green btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-2x fa-refresh"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;No Filter added to this category<br/>Sync with Feature?</button></center>');
```

The generated button looks like this:

[image]

I want it to look like this:

[image]

how can I do this? is it possible?

Comment: you can do it using css ?? add css code you tried ??

Comment: Give position absolute for the icon class, and try changing the left & right positions

Comment: is a cleaner solution possible?

    $('#divContent').after('<center><button style="position:relative" type="button" id="btnFiltersSave1" class="btn bg-green btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-2x fa-refresh" style="position:absolute;top:9px"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;No Filter added to this category<br/>Sync with Feature?</button></center>');

Answer (score 0):

Css:

```
div{
   position: absolute;
   top: 15px;/**or requried**/
}
```

and add parent div position relative